# How to persist grid view data across pages?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

How to persist grid view data when  moving across pages. when I click on browser back button, the data is gone.

Comment: Session state is one possible approach.

Answer (score 0):

Bind data to `GridView` as below

```
if(Session["GridData"] != null)
{
      gridId.DataSource = YourDataSource;
      gridId.DataBind();
}
else
{
      //Calculate YourDataSourse
      gridId.DataSource = YourDataSource;
      gridId.DataBind();

      Session["GridData"] = YourDataSource
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, to set a value in session variable:

```
If System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("MyVariable") Is Nothing Then
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session(“MyVariable”) = DataSource
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Session for your case
try this

```
if ( Session["Data"] != null )
{
      DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["Data"];
      GridView1.DataSource = YourDataSource;
      GridView1.DataBind();
}
else
{
      DataTable dt = datasource;
      GridView1.DataSource = dt;
      GridView1.DataBind();
      Session["Data"] = dt;
}
```

whenever your session is null it will fill data from your datasource and Save your DataTable to session. Fatch the value from session next time. Remember that `Session` Timeout is **20 Minutes**. If your Request goes to server after 20 Minutes you will lost your data in session. You can Manually increase the `Session Timeout` from `Web.Config`.